# psycopg2 binary package for windows and postgres 8?

Tags: python, windows, postgresql, binary, psycopg2

Where is the psycopg2 binary package for windows and postgres 8?

I can only find a release for postgres 9 on http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/

There is a link for older versions at the bottom of the page but it does not realy help.

EDIT: I could find them, see my answer below

Comment: Mark your answer below as the correct answer by clicking in the big "v" below the upvote and downvote settings.

Comment: Yes, you just can accept your own answer after [48 hours it was posted](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found  the binary packages for postgres 8 start at http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/index.2.2.1.html

The html pages are chained, so I simply had to repeat the scroll down and click the "old versions" links on the page several times.